# Associate allocate cursor result set question

Tags: java, stored-procedures, jdbc, db2

I'm trying to run this code I found in this link: http://www.sqlines.com/db2-to-oracle/process_result_sets_in_procedures

I'm pretty sure when I run my stored procedure, it returns the values I need, but when I put it to my allocate 'cur' and fetch the value, it returns nothing.

```
CALL MYSTOREDPROC();

ASSOCIATE RESULT SET LOCATOR (result) WITH PROCEDURE MYSTOREDPROC;
ALLOCATE cur CURSOR FOR RESULT SET result;
FETCH cur INTO p_name;
CLOSE cur;
```

1. I tried to run it directly to the db2 and it runs successfully meaning it runs without error but I can't confirm if it really returns a result set,
2. I tried to call it via jdbc, it returns this exception

   > Exception in thread "main" com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.SqlException:
   >   [ibm][db2][jcc][10100][10910]
   >   java.sql.CallableStatement.executeQuery() was called but no result set
   >   was returned. Use java.sql.CallableStatement.executeUpdate() for
   >   non-query

My question:

How will I know if the 'result' is really put in 'cur'?

Here is how I call my stored procedure:

```
String ret = "";
statement = connection.prepareCall("{CALL SP_CALLER(?)}");
statement.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
resultSet = statement.executeQuery();   
resultSet.next();
ret = resultSet.getString(1);   
resultSet.close();
closeAllConnection();
return ret;
```

based on the exception, it points out to db2, that it doesn't return any value.

UPDATED

Here's my stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ITRS.SP_CALLER()
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1

BEGIN

DECLARE loc_cursor RESULT_SET_LOCATOR VARYING;
DECLARE SQLSTATE CHAR(5) DEFAULT '00000';
DECLARE v_useraccountid SMALLINT;
DECLARE v_roleid SMALLINT;
DECLARE v_userid VARCHAR(20);
DECLARE v_username VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE v_lastlogindate TIMESTAMP;
DECLARE v_deleted SMALLINT;

DECLARE ret CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR
SELECT * from ITRS.DUMBTABLE where username='JOHN';


CALL ITRS.PR_USERACCOUNTGETALL();

ASSOCIATE RESULT SET LOCATOR (loc_cursor) WITH PROCEDURE ITRS.PR_USERACCOUNTGETALL;
ALLOCATE cur CURSOR FOR RESULT SET loc_cursor;

ins_loop: 
LOOP
FETCH cur INTO v_useraccountid,v_roleid,v_userid,v_username,v_lastlogindate,v_deleted;
  IF SQLSTATE <> '00000' THEN LEAVE ins_loop; END IF;
  INSERT INTO ITRS.DUMBTABLE(USERACCOUNTID,ROLEID,USERID,USERNAME,LASTLOGINDATE,DELETED)
 VALUES(v_useraccountid,v_roleid,v_userid,v_username,v_lastlogindate,v_deleted);
END LOOP ins_loop;

CLOSE cur;
open ret;
END
```

Comment: Show your java code calling this SP and processing the ResultSet.

Comment: i updated the post. kindly check Mark

Comment: Please show the code of your stored procedure

Comment: I updated the my post Mark. kindly check thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wrong sequence of calls.
You should use correct calls to retrieve a result set from a stored procedure.
[Retrieving a known number of result sets from a stored procedure in a JDBC application](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_t0052582.html):

```
CallableStatement cstmt;
ResultSet rs;
int i;
String s;
…
cstmt.execute();                        // Call the stored procedure       1 
rs = cstmt.getResultSet();              // Get the first result set        2 
while (rs.next()) {                     // Position the cursor             3 
 i = rs.getInt(1);                      // Retrieve current result set value
 System.out.println("Value from first result set = " + i);  
                                        // Print the value
}
```